# Linux (Deepin OS) Store

Tags: linux, debian

Search in Deepin 15.11 store is not working, How can i solve such a problem?

[Deepin store snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqkCC.png)

Comment: In terminal run `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`. Any error messages?

Comment: No errors but still search in store not working, it was working before an update(just after installing the system), is there is any way to rollback that update, thanks for help.